# spark scala: how to update a dataframe in place?

Tags: dataframe, scala, apache-spark

I have a huge dataframe with row over 100M and thousands of columns. I need to update elements of the dataframe. I could accomplish the task as shown below, but for reasons explained under the output, I am looking for better performance. The current solution I could find in `Spark 3.3.0-scala2.13.8` is:

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.Row
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions.{col, struct}

def ip_udf(c_names: Array[String]) = udf[String,Row]((r: Row) => {
    val row = Array.ofDim[String](c_names.length)

    // some minor modification to each value
    for (i <- 0 until row.length) {
        row(i) = "t_" + r.getAs(i)
    }
    row.mkString(",")
})

val columns = Seq("C1", "C2", "X1", "X2", "X3", "X4")
val data = Seq(("abc", "212", "1", "2", "3", "4"),("def", "436", "2", "2", "1", "81"),("abc", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1"))

val rdd1 = spark.sparkContext.parallelize(data)
val df1 = spark.createDataFrame(rdd1).toDF(columns:_*)
df1.show()

val col_names = df1.columns
val num_cols = col_names.length

val df2 = df1.withColumn("output",ip_udf(df1.columns)(struct("*"))).select(col("output"))
            .withColumn("words", split(col("output"), ","))
            .select((0 until num_cols).map(i => $"words".getItem(i).as("mod_"+col_names(i))): _*)
df2.show()
```

Input:

```
+---+---+---+---+---+---+
| C1| C2| X1| X2| X3| X4|
+---+---+---+---+---+---+
|abc|212|  1|  2|  3|  4|
|def|436|  2|  2|  1| 81|
|abc|  1|  1|  1|  1|  1|
+---+---+---+---+---+---+
```

Output:

```
+------+------+------+------+------+------+
|mod_C1|mod_C2|mod_X1|mod_X2|mod_X3|mod_X4|
+------+------+------+------+------+------+
| t_abc| t_212|   t_1|   t_2|   t_3|   t_4|
| t_def| t_436|   t_2|   t_2|   t_1|  t_81|
| t_abc|   t_1|   t_1|   t_1|   t_1|   t_1|
+------+------+------+------+------+------+
```

Reason for searching improvement over the current solution:
The dataframe is in terabytes with very huge number of rows and columns. So instead of creating intermediate stages, it could be faster if the dataframe is made `var` and update elements in place, one row at a time with a UDF. In fact, this is almost 50% slower than directly writing the CSV output as a one string per row to a file (inefficient for reading from file again as a dataframe)!

Though I could process at the level of `Row`, I am unable to find a way to write UDF that returns a `Row` itself so that update can be made more efficiently. I could not find any examples demonstrating such a functionality in Spark 3. I would be grateful if anyone can suggest an improvement.

Comment: What's the real usage? Reading from HDFS and writing back to HDFS? If so I'm not sure this supports "update in place" and that it would be significantly faster than writing a new file and electing the old one after.

Comment: The entire table is modified as required, that's the usage :) The issue is of delay due to intermediate steps that, if possible, could be avoided by replacing `x_i_j`s with `y_i_j`s, so that instead of hours it can be done much faster. Even if not in place (which I suspect is the case), if I can create a direct modified replica, that would be also almost as good.